# Serialisation issue when using JsonSerializer when retrieving Elasticsearch document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to retrieve Elasticsearch document and deserialize the json response into a particular type.

Here is the generic Document class

```
public class Document<T> where T : class
{
    public int _Seq_No { get; set; }
    public int _Primary_Term { get; set; }
    public T _Source { get; set; }
}
```

I have an Order class that represents T.

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
    //..other fields omitted...
}
```

I have the following method to get the Document from Elasticsearch.

```
public async Task<Document<T>> LoadDocument<T>(string orderId, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken = default) where T : class
{
   var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions {PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true};
   //.....code to get the document (as json) from the service omitted ...
   //deserialize
   var document = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Document<T>>(jsonDocument, jsonOptions);
   return document;
}
```

I've tried calling it like so:

```
var document = await _service.LoadDocument<Order>(orderId)
```

When I debugged the code I could see that the `_Seq_No` and `_Primary Term` properties were set with actual values that I expected but the `_Source` property (in this case the Order) the properties on the order defaulted to their default values instead of the actual values.

The `_source` property in the json document/response is populated so I'm unsure why deserialisation isn't working for this particular part.

Do i need to decorate the members in my `Order` class with `[JsonProperty(...)]`?

I would appreciate if someone could help me determine what I have missed from the deserialisation side of things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved this issue myself. I didn't have to do anything special to my classes.
I did update my Order class and decorated the fields with [JsonProperty(...)] as approprate.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to resolve the double nesting issue. I rebuilt my solution several times. Something in my local development environment was not correct.

I also decorated the properties in my Order class with `[JsonProperty(...)]` and set the value appropriately.